# What will be the Time complexity of the given algorithm, by substitution or recurrence tree method

Tags: algorithm, math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

[image]

What will be the time complexity  of this algorithm, can anyone explain itbin detail. We have just figured out that when n is in the form of 2^x then only it reaches the base case .
And we were taking it as T(n) = T(n/2) + T(3n+1)

Note this is not an infinite loop as collatz conjecture (*3n-1*).

Comment: This picture is ugly. Better remove it.

Comment: You are assuming that that Collatz Conjecture is true; that the number of steps is *finite.* If you find a way to get from that assumption to an upper bound on the number of steps, you will be famous.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is the length of the Collatz sequence starting from `n`.

See http://oeis.org/A006577.